# hadoop -0.20.0 cannot process bin/hadoop namenode-format

Tags: multithreading, hadoop, installation, multiprocessing

I follow this link in installing hadoop https://gist.github.com/tariqmislam/2159173
 but then I get the ff. error:

Von Ivan@Kalev /usr/local/hadoop-0.20.2

$ bin/hadoop namenode-'format'

bin/hadoop: line 258: C:/Program/bin/java: No such file or directory

bin/hadoop: line 289: C:/Program/bin/java: No such file or directory

bin/hadoop: line 289: exec: C:/Program/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory

---

I set my System variables in environmental variables section like this:

Variable Name : JAVA_HOME

Variable Number: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15\bin

and in my hadoop-env.ssh I set the path to: export JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/bin

I set this path because there are many subfolders in my Java dir

Answer (score 0):

there is a space in your JAVA_HOME:

```
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/bin
```

Comment: well...try to use quotes `JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/bin"`